# Scaling NinePatch image horizontally (without children, in a RelativeLayout)

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a NinePatch image, stretched horizontally.

I haven't used NinePatch much, but do have other NinePatches images working in other areas (e.g., as background of of Views with content), as expected.

I've attached a simplified version of what I'm experiencing.  Basically I want the dot to tile the center pixel horizontally.  The image will only ever expand horizontally.  It does not contain any other views.

I first tried setting just a single-pixel vertical path, then added a single-pixel horizontal path as well.  No difference.  In the preview panel of the NinePatch tool, it appears fine.

It's being used in a RelativeLayout, per the code sample below.  I've included lines that are commented out as other settings I've tried.

```
track = new ImageView(context);
track.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
//track.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
track.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_track);
//track.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_track);

LayoutParams trackLayout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//LayoutParams trackLayout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
trackLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
trackLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
trackLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

addView(track, trackLayout);
```

[image: sample]

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't figure it out.

Any insights are appreciated.

TYIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you misunderstood Ninepatch concept. try to understand by this image [image]

You can also try with this BetterNinePatch tool http://android.elex.pe.kr/a-better-9-patch-tool :)

[image]

try to create like this.

Comment: how did i misunderstand?  how would you achieve what i'm describing?

Comment: afaik, a single pixel cannot be "curved".

Comment: thanks.  turns out i was doing it right the whole time, just saving the image in the wrong directory.  +1 thanks for taking the time.